# chicago.sty and hyperref: hyperlink formatting

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing

`chicago.sty` offers a number of citation commands which may output a link to the bibliography if `hyperref` is used. As long as no page number is given, hyperlink formatting is as expected (cf. last column). However, if a page number is to be displayed, `citeN` and `shortciteN` do include it in the hyperlink, whereas the other commands don't.

How could these commands be redefined to let their optional parameter always be formatted as a hyperlink?*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{ref,
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  title     = {The TeXbook},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year      = {1986}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
                & cite          & \cite[p.\,1]{ref}         & \cite{ref}        \\
                & citeNP        & \citeNP[p.\,1]{ref}       & \citeNP{ref}      \\
                & citeA         & \citeA[p.\,1]{ref}        & \citeA{ref}       \\  
                & citeANP       & \citeANP[p.\,1]{ref}      & \citeANP{ref}     \\  
$\rightarrow$   & citeN         & \citeN[p.\,1]{ref}        & \citeN{ref}       \\ 
                & shortcite     & \shortcite[p.\,1]{ref}    & \shortcite{ref}   \\   
                & shortciteNP   & \shortciteNP[p.\,1]{ref}  & \shortciteNP{ref} \\   
                & shortciteA    & \shortciteA[p.\,1]{ref}   & \shortciteA{ref}  \\   
                & shortciteANP  & \shortciteANP[p.\,1]{ref} & \shortciteANP{ref}\\   
$\rightarrow$   & shortciteN    & \shortciteN[p.\,1]{ref}   & \shortciteN{ref}  \\   
                & citeyear      & \citeyear[p.\,1]{ref}     & \citeyear{ref}    \\
                & citeyearNP    & \citeyearNP[p.\,1]{ref}   & \citeyearNP{ref}  \\              
\end{tabular}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

*Changing `citeN` and `shortciteN` to *not* apply hyperlink formatting to their optional parameter is not an option. It would lead to the rather unpleasant result that while the parentheses *are* hyperlinks (which they should be, for the sake of consistency with each command's version without optional page parameter), something inside the parentheses, namely the optional parameter, is not a hyperlink.

Comment: Do you mean the `chicago.sty` file from 1992 (i.e., from before there was even a LaTeX2e)?  Surely whatever 'Chicago' guidelines it implements, it is massively out of date.  The 16th ed. came out in 2010, the 14th in 1993, and the 13th in 1982!  A better bet would be to use `biblatex-chicago` with `bibiatex` and (ideally) `biber`.

Comment: Indeed, that's the one I mean. And true, it is out of date. I have considered switching to `biblatex` and certainly will one day, but currently I'm locked into `chicago.sty`.

Comment: @jon: Just to clarify, in case any confusion arises: The file `chicago.sty` provides various citation *commands* but doesn't implement the BibTeX-related matter. That's left to `chicago.bst` -- which, as you note, is also massively out of date since it implements the guidlines of the 13th ed of the CMoS whereas we're now at the 16th ed.

Comment: @Mico -- Right!  I wrote too quickly (as usual).

Comment: @dgs -- There is also the 'achicago' bundle, which is more up to date than chicago.  No idea how useful it is. From the look of `chicago.sty` no provision is made to worry about what `hyperref` may or may not be doing, and the way parentheses are used in `\citeN` and `\shortciteN` seems very much hard-coded into the command definitions.

Comment: @jon Thanks for your recommendations. As I said, currently I'll stick with `chicago.sty`, which, in spite of its considerable age, is still quite prevalent at my institution. Regardless of my package choice, I'd consider the question to be an interesting problem which probably moreover isn't overly difficult to solve for someone being familiar with TeX syntax and the `hyperref` internals.

Comment: @jon It turned out that the solution indeed wasn't too difficult if you knew what to do, as Marco Daniel did. Nevertheless, thanks for your help.

Comment: @dgs -- I'm glad someone was able to help.  I actually thought you wanted the opposite of your request.  Probably too tired: I probably should've gone to bed rather than pretend I knew why `chicago.sty` defined \citeN and \shortciteN differently from the other commands.  (And I never got so far as to look at `hyperref`, but I now see why it is one of the last packages you're supposed to load.)  --- Even so, I suspect we have different views as to what an 'easy' solution would be.

Comment: (Deleted other comments that were suggesting how to (start to) make `\citeN` and `\shortciteN` behave like the other citation commands rather than the others behave like these two.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I want to recommend to avoid the old package `chicago` instead use `biblatex`

The package `hyperref` has a small support for the package `chicago`. It redefines some internal commands of `chicago.sty` to get the correct hyperlink. The internal definition is:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{chicago}{%
  \def\citeN{%
    \def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##1 (##3\@cite@opt)}%
    \@citedata@opt
  }%
  \def\shortciteN{%
    \def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##2 (##3\@cite@opt)}%
    \@citedata@opt
  }%
  \def\@citedata@opt{%
    \let\@cite@opt\@empty
    \@ifnextchar [{%
      \@tempswatrue
      \@citedatax@opt
    }{%
      \@tempswafalse
      \@citedatax[]%
    }%
  }%
  \def\@citedatax@opt[#1]{%
    \def\@cite@opt{, #1}%
    \@citedatax[{#1}]%
  }%
}{}
```

Based on this modification I took the original definition of `\citeyearNP` and `\citeyear` and modified them after the scheme of `hyperref`:

The original definition of `chicago.sty`:

```
\def\citeyear{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{(##1\if@tempswa , ##2\fi)}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##3}\@citedata}
\def\citeyearNP{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1\if@tempswa , ##2\fi}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##3}\@citedata}
```

Modified version:

```
\def\citeyear{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{(##1)}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}
\def\citeyearNP{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}
```

With this redefinition you will get:

[image]

Here the complete code. Of course the other cite commands must be redefined too. But I think that it can be done easily by you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\citeyear{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{(##1)}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}
\def\citeyearNP{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{ref,
  author    = {Donald E. Knuth},
  title     = {The TeXbook},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year      = {1986}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
                & cite          & \cite[p.\,1]{ref}         & \cite{ref}        \\
                & citeNP        & \citeNP[p.\,1]{ref}       & \citeNP{ref}      \\
                & citeA         & \citeA[p.\,1]{ref}        & \citeA{ref}       \\  
                & citeANP       & \citeANP[p.\,1]{ref}      & \citeANP{ref}     \\  
$\rightarrow$   & citeN         & \citeN[p.\,1]{ref}        & \citeN{ref}       \\ 
                & shortcite     & \shortcite[p.\,1]{ref}    & \shortcite{ref}   \\   
                & shortciteNP   & \shortciteNP[p.\,1]{ref}  & \shortciteNP{ref} \\   
                & shortciteA    & \shortciteA[p.\,1]{ref}   & \shortciteA{ref}  \\   
                & shortciteANP  & \shortciteANP[p.\,1]{ref} & \shortciteANP{ref}\\   
$\rightarrow$   & shortciteN    & \shortciteN[p.\,1]{ref}   & \shortciteN{ref}  \\   
                & citeyear      & \citeyear[p.\,1]{ref}     & \citeyear{ref}    \\
                & citeyearNP    & \citeyearNP[p.\,1]{ref}   & \citeyearNP{ref}  \\              
\end{tabular}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added the complete list of redefinitions. How could it be sent to the `hyperref` maintainer (as a feature request)? I did not see any contact information neither on CTAN nor in the manual.

Comment: @dgs: Type `texdoc oberdiek` and you will find the contact.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here's the complete list. It is tested to work even in the rare case that multiple references should share the same page number. All credit goes to @MarcoDaniel.

```
\makeatletter
\def\cite{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{(##1)}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##1 ##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}
\def\citeNP{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##1 ##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}

%\citeN already modified by hyperref 

\def\citeA{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{(##1)}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##1\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}
\def\citeANP{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##1\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}

\def\shortcite{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{(##1)}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##2 ##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}  
\def\shortciteNP{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##2 ##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}

%\shortciteN already modified by hyperref  

\def\shortciteA{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{(##1)}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##2\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}    
\def\shortciteANP{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##2\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}
\def\citeyear{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{(##1)}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}    
\def\citeyearNP{\def\@citeseppen{-1000}%
    \def\@cite##1##2{##1}%
    \def\citeauthoryear##1##2##3{##3\@cite@opt}\@citedata@opt}
\makeatother
```